# Copy Pose Location, Paste As World Location

Tags: animation, workflow, transforms

I would like to copy the current bone pose location, convert it into world location and paste this world location in the next key frame again in pose location.

Is it possible with a certain command?

Pose->World->[Next Frame]->World->Pose